# What is the best method of starting/ stoping js anime timeline on input

Tags: javascript, input, anime.js

I'm attempting to create an animation (using anime.js) that plays an animation timeline once when the users starts typing and will loop for the duration that the user is typing in the input box. When the user stops typing the animation will complete its current loop and stop playing.

Here's my progress at the moment, you can observe the animation working incorrectly: https://codepen.io/andrewbentley/full/XqMrze

Here's what my anime.js code timeline:

```
var basicTimeline = anime.timeline({
  loop: true,
  autoplay: false,
  duration: 700
});

basicTimeline
  .add({
    targets: '#circ1',
    duration: 100,
    translateY: -10,
    easing: 'easeInQuad' 
  })
  .add({
    targets: '#circ1',
    duration: 100,
    translateY: 0,
    easing: 'easeInQuad'
  })
  .add({
    targets: '#circ2',
    duration: 100,
    translateY: -10,
    easing: 'easeInQuad'
  })
  .add({
    targets: '#circ2',
    duration: 100,
    translateY: 0,
    easing: 'easeInQuad'
  })
  .add({
    targets: '#circ3',
    duration: 100,
    translateY: -10,
    easing: 'easeInQuad'
  })
  .add({
    targets: '#circ3',
    duration: 100,
    translateY: 0,
    easing: 'easeInQuad'
   })
  .add({
    targets: '#circ3',
    delay: 100
});

document.querySelector('#email').onkeypress = basicTimeline.play;
document.querySelector('#email').onkeyup = basicTimeline.pause;
```

Is anyone able to advise me as to the best way of achieving the desired effect whilst using anime.js timeline utility and the use of event listeners such as `onkeypress`, `onkeyup` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a timer which pauses your animation after some time of inactivity.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qYoPKQ

```
var timer = false;
document.querySelector('#email').onkeypress = function () {
  if(basicTimeline.paused) basicTimeline.play();
  if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    basicTimeline.pause();
    basicTimeline.reset();
  }, 500);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue of stopping an animation at the end of the current loop has been raised here:
[on github](https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime/issues/574) There are some good suggestions there.

Perhaps the best one is from [Edrees Jalili](https://github.com/edreesjalili)

```js
function pausableLoopAnime({loopComplete, ...options}) {
  const instance = anime({
    ...options,
    loop: true,
    loopComplete: function(anim) {
        if(instance.shouldPause) anim.pause();
        if(typeof loopComplete === 'function') loopComplete(anim);
    }
  });
  instance.pauseOnLoopComplete = () => instance.shouldPause = true;
  return instance;
}

const animation= pausableLoopAnime({
  targets: '.polymorph',
  points: [
      { value: '215, 110 0, 110 0, 0 47.7, 0 67, 76' },
      { value: '215, 110 0, 110 0, 0 0, 0 67, 76' }
  ],
  easing: 'easeOutQuad',
  duration: 1200,
});

setTimeout(animation.pauseOnLoopComplete, 100)
```